# How to create a .csv file without breaking lines?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a .csv file which can be perfectly read in a pandas DataFrame, it has one column, let's call it `Column1` with 5 different values (`0,1,2,3,4`) and I am trying to create four new csv files, one for each of my categories.

To do so I am using `pd.to_csv` with its default parameters. However my problem is that the second column of my dataframe is formed by strings (which quotation marks around them) which may have break points inside them so when I create the new file the data of `Column2` will be moved to `Column1`. Like so:

```
Column1           Column2
   0              'this is correct'
   1              'this
is not correct'
```

Do you have any clue of how could I create a new dataframe without this effect? I can not put the original file where I am reading my dataset from as is so heavy but if needed I could try to create an example.

I have tried the `line_separator = \n` argument in `pandas.to_csv()` but it is giving mistake as each line of the file I am reading is supposed to be one line in my new file.

Comment: Perhaps you have an XY problem. Why is it important for you to do this? In raw text, yes, there will be a new line in the csv, but that stands to reason as the field contains a newline. How else should it behave? You say "the data is moved to Column 1", but in what sense is this true? Raw text files don't have "columns". The funny entry gets quoted, so it will still be parsed properly. For example, you can read the resulting file with `pd.read_csv` or open it with Excel and it works fine.

Comment: Not easy create DataFrame with your problem, is possible use `replace` like `df.Column2.str.replace(r'\r\n', '')` ? | Or `df.Column2.str.replace(r'\n', '')` ?

Comment: I didn't have any problems making an example `DataFrame`, e.g. `pd.DataFrame([[0, 'hi'], [1, 'line\nbreak']]).to_csv('temp.csv')`.

Answer (score 1):

You have several solutions for your problem.

1- You want to remove all \n from your column, then use

```
d.Column2 = d.Column2.apply(lambda x : x.replace('\n', ''))
```

Then you print on file.

2- You want to keep the \n, well it is information. You can add quotechars.

```
pd.to_csv(..., quotechars='"') #but this is by default right ?
```

You get :

> "Column1"     "Column2"
>
> "0"                  "'this
>   is correct'"
>
> "1"                  "'this
>
> is not correct'"

Everything is correct here as any good tool will use quotes to know the last line is part of the Column2.

Just use the same value for parameter quotechars when you read the file with pandas.

Answer (score 1):

I knew this is an old question but the above answers seem do not solve it perfectly.

I have a similar problem recently and figured out how to solve it. This cause is that the second value in your `Column2` has a character `\r` or `\n` that will create a new line. Since I'm using Mac, if the value contains `\r`, it will break a new line when I apply `data.to_csv`, where `data` is a `pd.DataFrame` object.

**Solution**

Put `escapechar="\r"` or `escapechar="\n"`argument in `data.to_csv()`.

`data.to_csv(file_path, escapechar="\r")`.

**Example**

Reproduce the breaking line problem:

`data_dict== {'Column1': [1,2], 'Column2': ["this is correct", "this\ris not correct"]}`

`data_df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)`

save to csv

`data_df.to_csv('test.csv')`

Then we will have the breaking lines problem as you mentioned.

If we do `data_df.to_csv('test.csv', escapechar="\r")`, the problem will be solved and the character `\r` will also exist.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that problem, you can create a new `dictionary` for each category and use pandas to create a csv for each dictionary, if you get stuck, i'll provide an example

Answer (score 0):

None of the other suggestions worked for me. I simply replaced all `\n` with `\\n` before saving to CSV and it'll preserve the newline character.

```
df.Column2 = df.Column2.apply(lambda x : x.replace('\n', '\\n'))
df.to_csv("df.csv", index=False)
```